# I need ideas for webservice(uploading data)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm trying a diff approach to my system, before im using an ssis to extract data from  an excel file(this excel file is generated by another system lets call it excel generator system) and then upload it to database via a stored procedure, now what we wanted is to eliminate the excel data to avoid parsing and the likes.. my question is this, what can i do to eliminate the use of excel what can i suggest to the makers of the excel generator system for them to upload the data immediately to my webservice. What Should the excel generator system output be? list? data table?

the excel file contains the ff columns:

emp id,
first name,
middle name,
last name
and so on

I need some ideas on how  to create my webservice and what the output should the excel generator system should be. Because I will then use whatever output it will get from this excel data system and then select it according to its column name and then save it to a db.

Comment: You never told us where the "excel generator system" is getting its data from.

Comment: they are getting it from a set of tables that is off limits to me. I can ask them to produce an output that i can use for my webservice.. but the question is what? should i ask them to produce a list? a datatable? and the likes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options,

1. Use an array of employees (create an employee class and mark it serializable), in your web service take a parameter of employee array objects.  This approaches allows for interoperability with non MS solutions.

   e.g. bool SendEmployeeData(employee[] emp) // return true if upload succeeds.
2. OR in your web service take a parameter of dataset (by default it's serializable), then in the code extract the datatable and the records, you and the uploader must agree on the data format.